# String value to Integer array

Tags: vb.net, string

I have the string like `TE_2015-2016_UnKnown,TE_2014-2015_UnKnown,TE_2013-2014_UnKnown`. I want to get integer array `(2015,2016,2014,2015,2013,2014)` in this string. How to do it?

**EDIT**

I try like this

```
Dim x As String = "TE_2015-2016_UnKnown,TE_2014-2015_UnKnown,TE_2013-2014_UnKnown"

        Dim y As String = String.Empty

        For Each xstr As String In x.Split(",")

            y &= xstr.Split("_")(1).Replace("-", ",")

        Next

        Dim xarr() As Integer = Array.ConvertAll(y.Split(","), Function(str) Int32.Parse(str))
```

Its return output

```
(0): "2015"
(1): "20162014"
(2): "20152013"
(3): "2014"
```

But i want

```
 (0): "2015"
 (1): "2016"
 (2): "2014"
 (3): "2015"
 (4): "2013"
 (5): "2014"
```

**Note** : `TE` and `Unknown` not a static string. I give the example string.

Comment: We help those that help themselves. What have you tried? We will help to debug your code, but we will not write it for you. Please post any code that you have tired, along with a detailed description of what exactly you are having a problem with.

Comment: @MattClark i wrote the code with for loop. But i want with out loop then only i am not post the code

Comment: We can not help you if you do not post code.. Please edit your question to provide the appropriate information.

Comment: @MattClark Now see my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach using Regular Expressions:

```
    Dim data As String = "TE_2015-2016_UnKnown,TE_2014-2015_UnKnown,TE_2013-2014_UnKnown"

    Dim strNumbers As New List(Of String)
    For Each m As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match In System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(data, "\d+")
        strNumbers.Add(m.ToString)
    Next

    Dim numbers() As Integer = Array.ConvertAll(strNumbers.ToArray, Function(x) Int32.Parse(x))

    For Each number As Integer In numbers
        Debug.Print(number)
    Next
```

EDIT: Another variation without using loops....

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim data As String = "TE_2015-2016_UnKnown,TE_2014-2015_UnKnown,TE_2013-2014_UnKnown"

        Dim numbers = (From n In Regex.Matches(data, "\d+") Select Integer.Parse(n.value)).ToArray

        For Each number As Integer In numbers
            Debug.Print(number)
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks sir. its possible with out loop?

Answer (score 0):

[Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) it with '_' and '-' and then select ones which can be parsed

```
Int32 value
String s = "TE_2015-2016_UnKnown,TE_2014-2015_UnKnown,TE_2013-2014_UnKnown"
s.Split(new ['-', '_']).Where(Function(w) Int32.TryParse(w, out value))
```